# GCP - Place to change new IP in wordpress on VM restart

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have wordpress installed on GCP. Yesterday, I restarted the VM due to which my external IP changed. Due to this, fontawesome and some other URL's are still pointing to old IP. Where should I make the changes to fix it.

I have avada theme installed.

This url is not getting loaded
file:wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/assets/fonts/fontawesome/webfonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution is specific to Avada

After Site Migration
In some cases, when users migrate sites, the Font Awesome files can still show a path to the old site, and this causes the font to now show. Resetting the Fusion Caches easily fixes this (Avada > Theme Options > Performance > Reset Fusion Caches).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you would have to change all of the URLs manually in order to reconnect them with WordPress. From what you have written it may be prudent for you to get a static external IP for your VM [1].

[1] Reserving a static external IP address :
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

Comment: I have already changed the URL in database. But couldn't find font-awesome specific url change.